# What does "editorial lines" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> The journalist's purpose is to deliver the facts, and not to manipulate them. This requires non-adherence to editorial lines.

What does "editorial lines" mean in this context?

Answer (score 1):

Editorial lines in the sense of editorial guidances, that is the recommended official way of dealing with the news.